# Retrieve system properties via twiddle

Tags: properties, jboss, classpath, twiddle

I am trying to retrieve system properties from JMX-console using `twiddle` in jboss4.3.

The following command works and provides me value of a single property...

```
twiddle.sh -u<username> -p<password> -Djnp.disableDiscovery 
--server=localhost:<port>
invoke 'jboss:name=SystemProperties,type=Service' get 
<SYSTEM PROPERTY NAME>
```

But when i try to get all properties in a single attempt it doesn't work...

```
twiddle.sh -u<username> -p<password> -Djnp.disableDiscovery 
--server=localhost:<port> 
invoke 'jboss:name=SystemProperties,type=Service' showAll
```

and shows following exception:

```
00:02:21,773 ERROR [Twiddle] Exec failed
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.console.twiddle.command.InvokeCommand.invoke(InvokeCommand.java:234)
        at org.jboss.console.twiddle.command.InvokeCommand.execute(InvokeCommand.java:282)
        at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.main(Twiddle.java:306)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService$HTMLMap (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:375)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:165)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:247)
        at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:197)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1575)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
        at java.rmi.MarshalledObject.get(MarshalledObject.java:142)
        at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.interfaces.JRMPInvokerProxy.invoke(JRMPInvokerProxy.java:134)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invokeInvoker(InvokerInterceptor.java:365)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invoke(InvokerInterceptor.java:197)
        at org.jboss.jmx.connector.invoker.client.InvokerAdaptorClientInterceptor.invoke(InvokerAdaptorClientInterceptor.java:66)
        at org.jboss.proxy.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:70)
        at org.jboss.proxy.ClientMethodInterceptor.invoke(ClientMethodInterceptor.java:74)
        at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:100)
        ... 4 more
```

Any clues??

### EDIT

After adding `properties-plugin.jar` the error changes to this:

```
01:51:36,366 ERROR [Twiddle] Exec failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: No property editor for type: class org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService$HTMLMap
        at org.jboss.util.propertyeditor.PropertyEditors.getEditor(PropertyEditors.java:176)
        at org.jboss.console.twiddle.command.InvokeCommand.invoke(InvokeCommand.java:244)
        at org.jboss.console.twiddle.command.InvokeCommand.execute(InvokeCommand.java:282)
        at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.main(Twiddle.java:306)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this error is that `showAll` returns object of custom class `org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService$HTMLMap` that is not present on twiddle's classpath.

Just add to your twiddle.sh:

```
JBOSS_CLASSPATH="$JBOSS_CLASSPATH:$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib/properties-plugin.jar"
```

Note, it's for JBoss 4.x. You didn't mention version. But stacktrace suggests that it is JBoss 4.x.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The exception trace has changed now... check the edit.

Comment: What is exact version of JBoss? I can't reproduce the new exception with JBoss AS 4.2.3. It just works.

Comment: `INFO  [Server] Release ID: JBoss [EAP] 4.3.0.GA_CP01 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_4_3_0_GA_CP01 date=200804211657)`

Comment: Do I need to register the property editor or something?? http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/admindevel326/html/ch10.html

Comment: I have no extra editors configured for mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.PropertyEditorManagerService" in deploy/properties-service.xml. Try running twiddle.sh from clean JBoss 4.2.3.GA distribution. You can also check url `/jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor?action=inspectMBean&name=jboss%3Atype%3DService%2Cname%3DSystemProperties`. As showAll in twiddle outputs html fragment anyway.

Comment: Do we need to uncomment `<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.PropertyEditorManagerService" name="jboss:type=Service,name=BootstrapEditors">` from `server/deploy/instance/conf/jboss-service.xml`

Comment: I have it commented out too. Anyway only HashMapEditor could be a cure but no such thing is present anywhere.